# Firebase Push Notification Sending Twice

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending push notification to android device using FCM via PHP Curl. I have observed very strange issue where it is sending Push Notification twice to same device again.

The only thing I changed was to modify the Push notification title to my custom and it behaved weirdly.

See here is my code to send Push notification

```
$server_key = env('PUSH_NOTIFICATION_KEY');
        $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

        $sendData['title'] = 'Lol';
        $sendData['body'] = $data['message'];
        
        $fields = array();
        $fields = array (
            'registration_ids' => array (
                    $target
            )
        );
        $fields['data']['click_action'] = $data['click_action'];
        $fields['data']['click_action_id'] = $data['click_action_id'];
        $fields['data']['click_action_name'] = $data['click_action_name'];
        $fields['data']['type'] = $data['click_action'];
        $fields['data']['uuid'] = $data['click_action_id'];
        $fields['data']['notification_uuid'] = $data['notification_uuid'];
        $fields['data']['comment_uuid'] = $data['comment_uuid'];
        
        $fields['notification'] = $sendData;

        $fields = json_encode ( $fields );


        $headers = array(
            'Content-Type:application/json',
            'Authorization:key=' . $server_key
        );

        $ch = curl_init ();
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields );

        $result = curl_exec ( $ch );
        echo $result;
        curl_close ( $ch );
```

If I modify

```
$sendData['title'] = 'PUSH_APP_TITLE';
```

It works fine if I send Push app title but I need to customize the title.

Has anyone faced same behaviour ?

Thanks

Comment: I think your laravel method for sending notifications is calling twice.

Comment: I specifically checked that it is not calling